# Azure Container Instance not showing up in azure portal

Tags: azure

I create an azure container instance using the following code:

```
                containerGroup = await azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerName)
                    .WithRegion("West Europe")
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup(configuration.ContainerResourceGroup)
                    .WithLinux()
                    .WithPublicImageRegistryOnly()
                    .WithoutVolume()
                    .DefineContainerInstance(containerName)
                    .WithImage("selenium/standalone-chrome")
                    .WithExternalTcpPort(4444)
                    .Attach()
                    .CreateAsync(ct);
```

However the container sometimes shows up in the Azure portal, sometimes does not. (Yes I have refreshed the portal multiple times) I run the following command in powershell:

```
Get-AzureRmContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName XXXX
```

and it shows the azure container instance as running:

[image]

I can also see the container running programmatically:

```
IContainerGroup containerGroup = await azure.ContainerGroups.GetByResourceGroupAsync(configuration.ContainerResourceGroup, containerName);
```

Why is the portal not working? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Any filters set in the portal?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If there was it wouldn't explain how sometimes I can see the container and sometimes I can't